# Incutio XML-RPC server sends response as HTML and not XML

Tags: php, xml-rpc, server-configuration

I'm using the [Incutio XML-RPC Library](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/) for exchanging data between a app and a database located on a server.

I have tested my Incutio XML-RPC server side implementation on 2 different servers:

The first server does exactly what it is supposed to do. It executes the called functions and returns response via XML to the caller.

The same code is running on an other Ubuntu-Server. Here the implementation gets the same method call, but it answers with the HTML response of the server side and not XML:

```
XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.
```

So in the end, a parsing error is thrown from the caller, because it expects the XML response.
What could have went wrong during the configuration of the server? (PHP, Apache, ..., ?, ?)